# Meteor SimpleSchema and _id field

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

A little bit question, did you include the `_id` field into your SimpleSchema ?

If the answer is ***no !*** and if you use `Collection2`, did you check the `_id` argument into your methods ?

Example :

```
equipments.update': (equipmentId, equipment) => {
    check({ _id: equipmentId }, Equipments.schema.pick('_id'));
    check(equipment, Equipments.schema.omit('_id'));
    // ...
},
```

Thanks :-)
Aurélien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no reason to include the `_id` field unless you want to force your mongo document IDs to follow a specific format in which case, you may explicitly specify the `_id` field in `simple shcema` and have a custom function / autoValue generate the value of the field.
2. From what I know, `collection2` usually drops the `_id` field before it runs `autoValue`. Reference: [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/342)